# Round Double and Cast to String

Tags: c++

I suppose this question is a follow up to a previous question I had regarding casting a double to a string.

I have an API where I'm given a string which represents a number.  I need to round this number to 2 decimals of precision and return it as a string.  My attempt to do this follows:

```
void formatPercentCommon(std::string& percent, const std::string& value, Config& config)
{
    double number = boost::lexical_cast<double>(value);
    if (config.total == 0)
    {
        std::ostringstream err;
        err << "Cannot calculate percent from zero total.";
        throw std::runtime_error(err.str());
    }
    number = (number/config.total)*100;
    // Format the string to only return 2 decimals of precision
    number = floor(number*100 + .5)/100;
    percent = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(number);

    return;
}
```

Unfortunately the cast captures "unrounded" values.  (i.e. number = 30.63, percent = 30.629999999999)  Can anyone suggest a clean way to round a double and cast it to a string so I get what one would naturally want?

Thanks in advance for the help.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Streams are the usual formatting facility in C++. In this case, a stringstream will do the trick:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << number;
percent = ss.str();
```

You are probably already familiar with `setprecision` from your previous post. [`fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/)
here is used to make the precision affect the number of digits after the decimal point, instead of setting the number of significant digits for the whole number.

Comment: Much thanks!  I really didn't want to have to resort to creating a temporary character array and format using snprintf().  :)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this, but I believe that the following should work:

```
string RoundedCast(double toCast, unsigned precision = 2u) {
    ostringstream result;
    result << setprecision(precision) << toCast;
    return result.str();
}
```

This uses the `setprecision` manipulator to change the precision of the `ostringstream` that is doing the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

```
double value = 12.00000;

std::cout << std::to_string(value).substr(0, 5) << std::endl;
```

Converting to a string while creating a substring will truncate extra zeros if you cannot use `round()` for some reason. I ran into this situation the other day.

This would come out as 12.00 (don't forget the decimal character!)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I haven't been on this site in a long time and I forgot to make use of the code editor.  Will definitely remember to format next time!

Comment: i used something like
`res = res.substr(0, res.length() - 5);`
to chop extra zeros off

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that does everything you want without re-inventing the wheel.

```
void formatPercentCommon(std::string& percent, const std::string& value, Config& config)
{   
     std::stringstream fmt(value);
     double temp;
     fmt >> temp;
     temp = (temp/config.total)*100;
     fmt.str("");
     fmt.seekp(0);
     fmt.seekg(0);
     fmt.precision( 2 );
     fmt << std::fixed << temp;
     percent = fmt.str();
}
```